# PowerShell C# PrintWindow() output not working

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi

EDIT: **RESOLVED**

I have now taken a slightly similar approach and still using the PrintWindow() API call, but if I can get this working, then I should be able to achieve what I want. I am receiving an error show in the image below **"Method invocation failed because [ScreenCapture] does not contain a method named 'PrintWindow'"**.

Majority of this is my lack of knowledge with C# and integrating into PowerShell. Can someone please help determine the cause of my error and how to properly correct it? Will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
$code = @'
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public class ScreenCapture
{

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

public static Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd)    
{       
    RECT rc;        
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);        
    Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);        
    IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();        

    PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);  

    gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);               
    gfxBmp.Dispose(); 

    bmp.Save(@"C:\TestScreenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);

    return bmp;   
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    private int _Left;
    private int _Top;
    private int _Right;
    private int _Bottom;

    public RECT(RECT Rectangle) : this(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom)
    {
    }
    public RECT(int Left, int Top, int Right, int Bottom)
    {
        _Left = Left;
        _Top = Top;
        _Right = Right;
        _Bottom = Bottom;
    }

    public int X {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Y {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Left {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Top {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Right {
        get { return _Right; }
        set { _Right = value; }
    }
    public int Bottom {
        get { return _Bottom; }
        set { _Bottom = value; }
    }
    public int Height {
        get { return _Bottom - _Top; }
        set { _Bottom = value + _Top; }
    }
    public int Width {
        get { return _Right - _Left; }
        set { _Right = value + _Left; }
    }
    public Point Location {
        get { return new Point(Left, Top); }
        set {
            _Left = value.X;
            _Top = value.Y;
        }
    }
    public Size Size {
        get { return new Size(Width, Height); }
        set {
            _Right = value.Width + _Left;
            _Bottom = value.Height + _Top;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator Rectangle(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return new Rectangle(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
    }
    public static implicit operator RECT(Rectangle Rectangle)
    {
        return new RECT(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return !Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{Left: " + _Left + "; " + "Top: " + _Top + "; Right: " + _Right + "; Bottom: " + _Bottom + "}";
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return Rectangle.Left == _Left && Rectangle.Top == _Top && Rectangle.Right == _Right && Rectangle.Bottom == _Bottom;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object Object)
    {
        if (Object is RECT) {
            return Equals((RECT)Object);
        } else if (Object is Rectangle) {
            return Equals(new RECT((Rectangle)Object));
        }

        return false;
    }
}

}


'@

# Loads/Adds User Add-Type (With correct Assemblies)
Add-type $code -ReferencedAssemblies 'System.Windows.Forms','System.Drawing' 

# Creates the object for the Function (ScreenShotAC.ScreenCapture)
$ScreenCapture = New-Object ScreenCapture 

# Grabs 
$Handle = (Get-Process -Name Notepad).MainWindowHandle
$ScreenCapture.PrintWindow($Handle)
```

*I have tried various other solutions into PowerShell, but this is the closest I have gotten to getting PrintWindow() working via a call in PowerShell. Ideally, I would want the current code to work unless someone can clean up what I have done and explain the said changes.

**- HERE IS THE NEW WORKING CODE -** (Enjoy!)

```
$code = @'
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public class ScreenCapture
{

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

public Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd)    
{       
    RECT rc;        
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);        
    Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);        
    IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();        

    PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 1);  

    gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);               
    gfxBmp.Dispose(); 

    bmp.Save("TestScreenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);

    return bmp;   
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    private int _Left;
    private int _Top;
    private int _Right;
    private int _Bottom;

    public RECT(RECT Rectangle) : this(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom)
    {
    }
    public RECT(int Left, int Top, int Right, int Bottom)
    {
        _Left = Left;
        _Top = Top;
        _Right = Right;
        _Bottom = Bottom;
    }

    public int X {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Y {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Left {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Top {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Right {
        get { return _Right; }
        set { _Right = value; }
    }
    public int Bottom {
        get { return _Bottom; }
        set { _Bottom = value; }
    }
    public int Height {
        get { return _Bottom - _Top; }
        set { _Bottom = value + _Top; }
    }
    public int Width {
        get { return _Right - _Left; }
        set { _Right = value + _Left; }
    }
    public Point Location {
        get { return new Point(Left, Top); }
        set {
            _Left = value.X;
            _Top = value.Y;
        }
    }
    public Size Size {
        get { return new Size(Width, Height); }
        set {
            _Right = value.Width + _Left;
            _Bottom = value.Height + _Top;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator Rectangle(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return new Rectangle(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
    }
    public static implicit operator RECT(Rectangle Rectangle)
    {
        return new RECT(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return !Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{Left: " + _Left + "; " + "Top: " + _Top + "; Right: " + _Right + "; Bottom: " + _Bottom + "}";
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return Rectangle.Left == _Left && Rectangle.Top == _Top && Rectangle.Right == _Right && Rectangle.Bottom == _Bottom;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object Object)
    {
        if (Object is RECT) {
            return Equals((RECT)Object);
        } else if (Object is Rectangle) {
            return Equals(new RECT((Rectangle)Object));
        }

        return false;
    }
}

}


'@

# Loads/Adds User Add-Type (With correct Assemblies)
Add-type $code -ReferencedAssemblies 'System.Windows.Forms','System.Drawing' 

# Creates the object for the Function (ScreenShotAC.ScreenCapture)
$ScreenCapture = New-Object ScreenCapture 

# Grabs 
$Handle = (Get-Process -Name Notepad).MainWindowHandle
$ScreenCapture.PrintWindow($Handle)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. If I were to _guess_, the problem is related to not finding a window with the desired class and title, and that _some_ subsequent call fails with a window handle that is `NULL`.

Comment: So I did double check and it must be passing a NULL which is why it is throwing the error. So, am I doing something wrong in the "CaptureWindow()" call?

I am using the FindWindow() to produce the "hwnd" for the PrintWindow(), but clearly that is not working.  Is there a better way to retrieve the hwnd since I already know the class and title of the application?

Comment: *Always* check the return values from win32 api calls - they often indicate success / failure, sometimes with an error code. ```FindWindow``` says, for example: “If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the window that has the specified class name and window name.
If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.” - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa#return-value. Note that you should use ```Marshal.GetLastWin32Error``` to get the last win32 error from *your* code

Comment: @AnonPowershellGuy1 Get-Process contains the HWND of applications (easy way to get the HWND without using P/Invoke calls)

Comment: I will give that a go and see why the FindWindow call is failing on providing the handle from my strings or at least give me a clue.

@bluuf I am aware you can definitely do this in PowerShell. Like this.. "$ProcessHandle = (Get-Process powershell).MainWindowHandle", but I don't know how to actively plug in that variable stored into the c# code I have. Which is why I tried doing that process within the c# code itself. I am always up for doing a better way if any good suggestions.

Comment: @AnonPowershellGuy1, you can redefine your method to `public void CaptureWindowToFile(string filename, IntPtr hWnd, ImageFormat format)` and pass in a window handle, but `(Get-Process javaw).MainWindowHandle` would _unconditionally_ report the main window handle of `javaw` processes, and to constrain by _window class_ would take further work. In light of that, error handling inside the C# code, on not being able to find the window of interest, is probably the better approach.

Comment: @mklement0 Okay, I will look the route for the NULL passed to the FindWindow call. 

Does anyone else see any issue wrong with strings I have used within the FindWindow?

Comment: The P/Invoke declaration of `FindWindow` looks correct (but note that you're implicitly using the ANSI version), but it looks like you're mistakenly passing the _process name_ rather than the _window title_ as the second argument.

Comment: I have updated my code in the main post to make things easier and I am now receiving an error stating the method is not within the call. So, at this point, I believe this fix is merely syntax and not understanding why the "PrintWindow" call is not working properly. Hopefully this helps makes the issue easier to understand.

Comment: >I have updated my code in the main post to make things easier and I am now receiving an error stating the method is not within the call. 

This is because your method is static but you are instantiating the screen capture class. Remove static from the definition of PrintWindow.

Comment: @vcsjones That was it! Removed that and had to adjust my "bmp.Save" and once that was good, it works as intended. Thanks a bunch for the help and everyone else who contributed. I will be changing my main post code to reflect the working outcome.

Comment: @AnonPowershellGuy1, glad to hear your worked it out, but please don't edit your _question_ with a solution, _post an answer_.

Comment: working solutions should be in an answer, not inside the question